# Check if the __thread keyword is available

Tags: c, multithreading, keyword

I cannot find any function/macro that can tell me if the `__thread` keyword/feature exists.

For example I want to do something like this without the user defining `HAS_TLS`

```c
#if HAS_TLS
    static __thread int mytlsdata;
#else
    static pthread_key_t mytlskey;
#endif
```

Comment: This heavily depends on your compiler. Which one are you using?

Comment: I´m using LLVM. But I´m looking for a cross compiler solution, if there is any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only *predefined*, *standard* thing that even comes close is,

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L && !defined __STDC_NO_THREADS__
    static _Thread_local int mytlsdata;
#endif
```

but this does not detect equivalent pre-C11 features, e.g. your `__thread`.  And assuming that `__STDC_VERSION__` accurately reflects a compiler's true capabilities has historically been ... unwise.

I would normally recommend [Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/) at this point, but it doesn't appear to have an off-the-shelf test to detect these, and if you've never done anything with Autoconf before, this is maybe not the place to start.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 1):

TLS support using keywords is compiler-specific.  LLVM/clang uses `__thread`, whereas VisualC++ uses `__declspec(thread)`, C++Builder supports both `__thread` and `__declspec(thread)`, etc.  There are no pre--compiler macros to determine if TLS keywords are available, or what keywords they actually are.  To write cross-platform code for TLS, you will have to detect specific compilers and code accordingly.